# Getting \r\n newlines to display properly in Mantis database

Tags: mysql, php, text, formatting

I've exported a Mantis project from one server to another and despite the MySQL SQL file (from which it was populated) showing:

```
(15375,'\r\n1. Log out\r\n\r\n2. When logging in, start ...
```

The final end-user view loses the \r\n and shows it only on one line:

```
1. Log out 2. When logging in, start typing
```

When viewing through phpMyAdmin, I can see the record properly:

```
1. Log out

2. When logging in, start typing
```

How can I correct this behavior when displaying this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to me incorrectly importing data from the old database.

http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=12683

> atrol (developer) 2011-01-14 07:10
>
> read file doc/INSTALL chapter
>   UPGRADING for the recommended way how
>   to upgrade. I am quite sure that your
>   step 1. is the reason for your
>   problem.
>
> You cleared table mantis_plugin_table,
>   so you disabled the
>   MantisCoreFormatting plugin which is
>   the one who is reponsible for
>   formatting the HTML output of issues.
>   (where also handling of newlines is
>   implemented)
>
> Futhermore you cleared
>   mantis_config_table. This is not a
>   problem for the moment, but will be a
>   problem in future for you when
>   upgrading. There is one setting to
>   hold the database schema version which
>   is used when upgrading.

---

> 2011-01-14 22:01
>
> Thanks atrol! That solved the problem
>   exactly. I also restored / set
>   mantis_config_table to its 1.2.4 value
>
> INSERT INTO `mantis_config_table`
>   VALUES
>   ('database_version',0,0,90,1,'183');

Answer (score 0):

\r\n is not displayed in HTML as a new line so it must be replaced with `<br />` (using the php function `nl2br`) or the text must be parsed into paragraphs (like wordpress does it).

I am not familiar with Mantis, but maybe there are some settings regarding the output of a text.

If you cannot find the place where to make the changes in Mantis code/settings then maybe a dirty hack would be to just replace it directly in the SQL file. But in this case, the `<br />` tag would probably show up when you'll edit the text later.

Comment: i think there should be some server level setting or Mantis level setting that should be taking care of it... Introducing the <br> would be a very last choice for me.